# Delete folder and files in PHP

Tags: php, unlink, rmdir

I have a question about the little code snippet below.
At the moment I use the first code snippet and it runs perfectly.
But wouldn't the second code be a better way to delete the folder and files in it?
My variable `$target` is everytime a path to the folder hwo needs to delete.

```
function deleteFilesAndDirectory($target)
{
    if(is_dir($target))
    {
        $files = glob($target . '*', GLOB_MARK);
        foreach($files as $file)
        {
            deleteFilesAndDirectory($file);      
        }
        rmdir($target);
    }
    elseif(is_file($target))
    {
        unlink($target);  
    }
}
```

Why this code shouldn't be used?

```
function deleteFilesAndDirectory($target)
{
    $files = glob($target . '*', GLOB_MARK);
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        unlink($file);      
    }
    rmdir($target);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The second will work fine, so long as the directory to be deleted does not contain any subdirectories.  To clean out subdirectories, a recursive function is the best way, which is why in the first code sample the function `deleteFilesAndDirectory()` calls itself.

Comment: ha thank you my friend, this was a short and clear answer for me :)
so i can use my short code because a never have any subdirectories.